# EntityFramework 5 CodeFirst - Get Function to Generate ID

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using CodeFirst at a new company and at my first Code Review I've been told that they don't use IDENTITY in their database tables.  :(  It makes me sad too, but I don't have any choice.

I'm allowed to use a simple function to generate my ID (which I then add to the DefaultValue on the Key field) - this works in SQL - but CodeFirst is just thinking I've got an ID of 0 each time.

I've tried all of the following ... can anyone assist please?

```
    public class Test
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: When exactly does EF returns `0` for `Test.Id`?

Comment: EF doesn't return 0 - but when I create my new Test object to add to the data context the ID is 0.  If it was null the function would probably kick it.  But then I'd have to make my IDs nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with ...

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

... and then overrode the SaveChanges method of the database context to catch the 0 ids ...

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var pendingChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added && e.Entity is IEntity);
        foreach (var entry in pendingChanges)
        {
            var entity = ((IEntity)entry.Entity);
            if (IsIDGenerated(entity)) continue;
            if (entity.ID == 0) entity.ID = GetNextID(entry.Entity.GetType());
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use a Guid then? The only reason I can think of for not using incrementing ids is when you need to migrate databases from time to time, and Guids are excellent for this.

Try this:

```
public class Foo {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Or in your Context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Property(f => f.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Comment: Oh God. Just be aware of the fact that it is not Entity Framework who auto-increments the id's, this is the database's job. Entity Framework, as far as I know, has no built-in module that does this, it just keeps your POCO's in sync when save your changes.